# Can I display model Post and model Topic all in one

Tags: django

Can I display model Post and model Topic all in one and add virtual field for know when loop it in template

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    excerpt = models.TextField(default='0')


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    excerpt = models.TextField(default='0')


    
class allon(Topic,Post):
 

def home(request): 
    all_posts = allon.objects.all( ) 

    return render(request, 'forum/home.html', {'edd': all_posts })
```

Comment: To can combine the two querysets of your models using chain

Comment: Are you asking for a model-like class/object that can be used to create querysets that combine multiple models?